# I have errors when I try to use PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am creating a website as a project for college and I want to include a contact page, of course. In this contact page, I created a form in which the user of the website can contact me (the admin of the website) and send me emails. I will display the code that I wrote immediately.

Can you also please tell me where exactly I should write the code? Maybe this is what I am doing wrong. So, the first time, I wrote it in a function and I called that function in the contact form. It didn't work. Then, I wrote the code for PHPMailer in a separate php file named send_mail.php and in the contact form (which is another file) i wrote the attribute action="send_mail.php" in the form tag. Is this right? Please tell me if I do this wrong.

Also, I want to receive those emails on my actual gmail account

I can't make it work and I have the following errors:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in D:\Xampp\htdocs\licenta_ecomm\public\send_mail.php on line 24
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::isSMTP() in D:\Xampp\htdocs\licenta_ecomm\public\send_mail.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\Xampp\htdocs\licenta_ecomm\public\send_mail.php on line 25

Now, I am pretty new to this and I haven't used PHPMailer before and I am a bit confused.
This is the contact form  (after comes the phpmailer code)

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading">Contacteaza-ne!</h2>
            <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted"><?php display_message(); ?></h3>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" action="send_mail.php" method="post" >
             <!--  EVENTUAL FUNCTIE??-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="nume_contact" class="form-control" placeholder="Numele *" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Introduceți numele dvs.">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email_contact" class="form-control" placeholder="Adresă e-mail *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Introduceți adresa e-mail">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="subiect" class="form-control" placeholder="Subiect *" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Introduceți subiectul">
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="mesaj" class="form-control" placeholder="Mesajul dvs. *" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Introduceți mesajul dorit"></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                        <div id="success"></div>
                        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Trimiteți mesaj</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the code that I wrote for sending the emails (send_mail.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
    require_once("../resources/config.php"); 

    //clase PHPMailer importante din namespace-ul global
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'D:\Xampp\composer\vendor\autoload.php';

    //variabilele din formularul de contact
    $nume_contact = escape_string($_POST['nume_contact']);
    $subiect = escape_string($_POST['subiect']);
    $email_from = escape_string($_POST['email_contact']);
    $mesaj = escape_string($_POST['mesaj']);

    try {

        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                   // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                        // Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';   // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'myemailaddress@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = 'secret';           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
        $mail->Port       = 587;                // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
    
        //sender
        $mail->setFrom('myemailaddress@gmail.com', 'H.P.');

        //recipient
        $mail->addAddress($email_from, $nume_contact);     // Add a recipient
 
        //body content
        $body = "<p>You received a message from: ".$nume_contact.". The message is: ".$mesaj."</p>";

        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subiect;
        $mail->Body    = $body;
        $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);
    
        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Where does the `$mail` comes from? The `config.php` script? You might haver forgotten to initialise it `$mail = new PHPMailer();`

Comment: @Claudio is right on point. Both your errors relate to the object not being properly created.